# Regex to find only when theres or isn't a specified character in between

Tags: python, regex

I have the string

> `"<whateverblahblah> <separatethis>"`

I want to use re.findall to return `[<whateverblahblah>, <dontincludethis>]` and not `["<whateverblahblah> <dontincludethis>"]`. This doesn't happen when I do

```
re.findall("<.*>")
```

Comment: You need to make it less greedy: `<.*?>`.

Comment: You can also use `<[^>]+>` as your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation about the regex engine might help you to better understand what's going on here.

What happens is that `<` matches the first `<`, then the next token is `.`, it matches *any* character (except newlines), it'll be repeated by the `*` token.

`*` is *greedy*, the engine repeats it as many times as it can, so the regex continues to try to match the `.` with next characters, resulting with matching

```
whateverblahblah> <separatethis>
```

But now the `>` won't be match as we reached end of the string, so the engine will go back (backtracking) and match only up to the `s`, and finally the `>` will match the `>` in your regex.

As already stated in the comments, to solve this you need to:

```
<.*?>
   ↑
```

Which means *laziness* instead.